# meteor collection.update is not updating document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to trigger an update within a client method (thinking to move into server later) as follows:

```
 Meteor.methods({
    // Calling this and passing in a currentSelected value = "avatar" on click
    'updateSelectedDocument' : function(currentSelected) {
      var current = LayoutVariations.findOne({elementID: currentSelected});
      var index = current.currentIndex;
      myCollection.update({_id :current._id}, {currentIndex: 2});
    }
 });
```

The .update should find the document and update that document's currentIndex property, which is an integer.

I ran the `myCollection.update({_id :current._id}, {currentIndex: 2});` in the console by passing in the _id (e.g. "GRvujvgBEmem3Dp3d") and it works. It's just not updating when I call it within a method and it's not throwing any errors.

Wondering what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator in your update to replace the value of the field `currentIndex` with the specified :

```
Meteor.methods({
     // Calling this and passing in a currentSelected value = "avatar" on click
     'updateSelectedDocument' : function(currentSelected) {
      var current = LayoutVariations.findOne({elementID: currentSelected});
      var index = current.currentIndex;
      myCollection.update({_id :current._id}, {$set: { currentIndex: 2 } }, function(error, affectedDocs) {
          if (error) {
              throw new Meteor.Error(500, error.message);
          } else {
              return "Update Successful";
          }
      });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried the `$set` operator. However I'm seeing the same behavior. Running `myCollection.update({_id :current._id}, {$set: { currentIndex: 2 } });` (with the actual _id) returns 1 and updates the document. But updating it from within the function doesn't seem to update the document in database.

Comment: Where are you calling the method on the client side `Meteor.call("updateSelectedDocument", function(error, result){...});`?

Comment: Just inside a template click event   ``
Template.frame.events({
    'click button': function () {
      Meteor.call('updateSelectedDocument', currentSelected);
    }
  });``

I just moved the method into the server (file under 'server' folder). And it appears to be updating correctly. Looks like CRUD methods only works on the server side then?

Comment: The general recommendation from Andrew Scala's [**introductory tutorial**](http://andrewscala.com/meteor/), he claims that Meteor.methods() should be used on the server when you want to update and modify your database documents: _The idea is that you define all the functions on the server that do dangerous stuff like modify and update data, and then let the client call those functions and get return values like regular functions. The client never sees the implementation and doesn’t personally modify the data. The server does all the work._

Comment: I think that makes a lot of sense. So these update methods just won't work on the client side even if in development mode. Something I'll keep in mind.